# How to add view to ClearCase Remote Client "My Views" dashboard?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I made a new view by CCRC CLI. Now I'm trying to set a new tab for it inside the CCRC dashboard, under "My Views". Do you know how to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by dashboard.

Once a ClearCase "web view" is created (by CLI or otherwise), it is automatically displayed in the "My Views" section of the ClearCase Navigator (shown here in its latest 7.1.2 version):

[image]

The "ClearCase Details" tab will reflect the current selected view.

Maybe a simple refresh is needed.